# how to solve this linux Timer error

Tags: c, linux, timer, clock

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BILLION  1000000000L;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    double accum;
    uint32 StartTime, StopTime;



    if( StartTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

StartTime = start.tv_sec + 0.0000000001 * start.tv_nsec;
    system( argv[1] ); // or it could be any calculation

    if( StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

StopTime = stop.tv_sec + 0.0000000001 * stop.tv_nsec;

 accum = StopTime - StartTime;
    printf( "%lf\n", accum );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

This program calculates the time required to
        execute the program specified as its first argument.
       The time is printed in seconds, on standard out.
I am calculating the start time and stop time to perform some computaion. I am able to get the start time and stop time for the computation but not able to find the difference between the start ans stop time i.e. accum.  could anyone help me in this ?

Comment: declare `StartTime` and `StopTime` as `double` if you wan't to assign this kind of expression `start.tv_sec + 0.0000000001 * start.tv_nsec;`

Comment: if it is uint32 how to modify it ??

Answer (score 0):

Remove `StartTime` and `StopTime`. Declare this function :

```
double to_double(struct timespec t) {
    return t.tv_sec + 0.0000000001 * t.tv_nsec;
}
```

And you'll get your deltatime this way :

```
accum = to_double(stop) - to_double(start);
```

Comment: I want to calculate the Starttime and Stoptime and difference between the two.

Comment: `StartTime = to_double(start)`, `StopTime = to_double(stop)`, `accum` is your difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `StartTime` and `StopTime` are both defined as integer types. The results of your calculations are not whole numbers but because the left hand side of the expressions are integers the results are getting truncated down to the integer part. Essentially, you are loosing the details provided by the `tv_nsec` field.

As suggested in the comments, declare `StartTime` and `StopTime` as doubles to fix that.

Change

```
uint32 StartTime, StopTime;
```

to

```
double StartTime, StopTime;
```